# Async TcpServer not listening to the client input

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, tcp

I am currently working on a TcpServer which multiple clients can connect to at the same time. Connecting and such are fine, i see the clients connecting through server logging. But when clients starts giving input nothing happens.

The code is posted below:

**TcpServer.cs:**

```
/// <summary>
/// TcpServer
/// </summary>
internal class TcpServer
{
    private readonly IConfigProvider _configProvider;
    private readonly ILoggingProvider _loggingProvider;
    private bool _accept;
    private TcpListener _listener;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public TcpServer(IConfigProvider configProvider, ILoggingProvider loggingProvider)
    {
        _configProvider = configProvider;
        _loggingProvider = loggingProvider;
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the TCP server and starts the listener.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            var address = IPAddress.Parse(_configProvider.Core.ListenAddress);
            _listener = new TcpListener(address, _configProvider.Core.ListenPort);

            _listener.Start();
            _accept = true;

            _loggingProvider.LogInfo($"Listening for connections on port {_configProvider.Core.ListenPort}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _loggingProvider.LogError($"Caught exception at TcpClient.StartServer(): {ex.Message}");
            _accept = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Listens on the open TCP socket for new connections.
    /// </summary>
    public void Listen()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (_listener != null && _accept)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (_tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        _loggingProvider.LogInfo("Stopping TCP listener");
                        _accept = false;
                        _listener.Stop();
                        break;
                    }

                    var clientTask = _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                    if (clientTask.Result != null)
                    {
                        var client = clientTask.Result;

                        _loggingProvider.LogInfo($"New connection from {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");

                        await SessionManager.Instance.NewDescriptorAsync(client);
                    }

                    _loggingProvider.LogInfo($"Number of connected users: {SessionManager.Instance.Descriptors.Count}");
                }
            }
        }, _tokenSource.Token);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the TCP server.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        _loggingProvider.LogInfo("SHUTDOWN: Requesting cancellation of TCP listener task");
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

**SessionManager function that is called:**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="Descriptor"/> from the <see cref="TcpClient"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="client">The <see cref="TcpClient"/> to create the descriptor from.</param>
    public async Task NewDescriptorAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        var newDescriptor = new Descriptor(client);
        Descriptors.Add(newDescriptor);            

        await newDescriptor.SendAsync("Username (new for new account): ");
    }
```

**SendAsync function for descriptor:**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Sends the specified message to the client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to send to the client.</param>
    public async Task SendAsync(string message)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
        {
            return;
        }

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        await Client.GetStream().WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me out..

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/davidfowl/MultiProtocolAspNetCore as a guide for how to write async high performance TCP servers on ASP.NET Core

Comment: Please add more information on whats wrong or not working. On the first view it looks good for me, except that you didn't use async all the way, which you should when you use async/await. Either async/await all the way or do it sync, not don't mix

Comment: According to the description your expectation is to get some data from clients on the server but there is no code which would read a data from the wire so either you didn't provide enough source code for that or your description isn't accurate.